# Calculate in R: Age of Infants in Year and Days

Tags: r, date

I am trying to calculate the age of an infant on a specific date. I managed to calculate the age in days and now I want to calculate the age in year + remaining days for those, older than a year. I thought this would be very easy, but so far have been stuck with the if condition. My ideal output would be a column for full years and a second column for either entire age in days or days additional to the amount of years. As most of the participants in my data are under 18monts, this column would be one year or 0.

My attempt so far with the eeptools packages:

```
Age$age_days <- age_calc(as.Date(Age$bith_date), enddate = as.Date(Age$participation_date), units = "days", precise = FALSE)
if (as.numeric(Age$age_days) > 365){Age$age_year = 1}
if (Age$age_days > 365){Age$age_days_remain - 365}
```

This produces the error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". How can I fix this?

If you have a more elegant solution I am happy to hear any ideas.
Thanks so much!

**Edit:** It would also be great to express the age in one variable in a "**year:months:day**" format. Any ideas how to achieve that easily?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps to avoid if statement?

1000 days for example:
`1000 %/% 365` for the years and
`1000 %% 365` for the remaining days.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. I guess you really have to know your operators :D It works. If anyone else tries this: using as.numeric avoids the error message for date-formats

Comment: @clarulatta_elphadora Most languages have a 'floor' integer division operator, to get the whole number while discarding the remainder, and a 'modulus' operator, to get the remainder. Once you know what they are called, you can look for them in other languages you use.